# How to stream video to and from Google Glass

Tags: android, video-streaming, google-glass

I really need help. I have spent days on stack overflow trying to find answers to my questions without any luck.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish...

I am trying to capture video from the google glass camera, and stream it to a WebRTC server online (or and RTSP server if possible)...

I am also trying to stream live video from a server to google glass in return.

I'm pretty much trying to achieve video conferencing on the google glass without going through any public streaming services like GHangouts or skype. Person A wearing Google glass can see Person B's webcam feed, Person B can see Person A's google glass camera feed.

I'm just beginning to code in Android but I'm a pretty strong Java programmer, so I'd appreciate anything you can offer - links, tips... anything.

I've been looking at this link stackoverflow.com/questions/2550847/streaming-video-from-android-camera-to-server but I just can't get it to work for me...

Someone called @MacD on that thread is pretty much trying to accomplish the same thing as me... but they didn't post their solution so I can't replicate it...

I also used this tutorial to stream video to android http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/streaming-video-in-android-apps--cms-19888, I'm not sure if it will work on glass though.

If anyone knows how to accomplish this, and doesn't mind dedicating a day or 2 via email to help me accomplish this, please email me at judithodili at gooogle mail. I'll be happy to pay you something for your time.

Thanks guys!